# I can't seem to call a method in class into another class. I have errors on my Main Class and my ApplicationUtilities class. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#

I can't seem to call a method in class into another class. I have errors on my Main Class to "DisplayApplicationInformation", "DisplayDivider", and "TerminateApplication" and also in my ApplicationUtilities class. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I have:

```
class ApplicationUtilities
{
    public static void DisplayAplicationInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Basic User Interface program");
        Console.WriteLine("CIS247A, Week 1 Lab");
        Console.WriteLine("Name: Lewis Jones");
        Console.WriteLine("This program accepts user input as a string, then make the appropriate data conversion");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}


public static void DisplayDivider(string outPutTitle)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("***************", + outPutTitle + "***************");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

public static void TerminateApplication()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using the Basic User Interface Program!!");

}
```

}

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        ApplicationUtilities AU;
        InputUtilities IU;

        //Declare Variables
        string name;
        string input;
        string outPut;
        int age;
        double gasMileage;
        string stringGasMileage;


        //Display Application Information from Application Utilities class
        DisplayApplicationInformation();
        ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Start Program");

        //Enter and Display user name
        AU.DisplayDivider("Name");
        name = IU.GetInput("Enter your name");
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);

        Console.WriteLine();

        //Enter and Display user age          
        AU.DisplayDivider("Age");
        input = IU.GetInput("Enter your age");
        age = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        Console.WriteLine("Your age is: " + age.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine();

        //Enter and Display user's gas mileage on current vehicle
        AU.DisplayDivider("Mileage");
        input = IU.GetInput("Enter gas mileage on current vehicle");
        gasMileage = Convert.ToDouble(input);
        Console.WriteLine("Your current Miles Per Gallon on your current vehicle is :" + gasMileage.ToString("N2"));

        Console.WriteLine();

        //Terminate the Application
        AU.TerminateApplication();

        //End the Main Program           
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is error text ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this isn't just a copy/paste mistake: DisplayDivider and TerminateApplication are not inside your ApplicationUtilities class scope.
Removing the second } after DisplayAplicationInformation() should fix that.

In your main-method you are trying to call your static methods with a class instance: ApplicationUtilities AU. That's not needed for static methods - so you should either remove the static keyword or call them directly:

```
ApplicationUtilities.DisplayApplicationInformation();
```

Also the method DisplayApplicationInformation got a typo in your class: DisplayAplicationInformation (a 'p' is missing)

Comment: you can call static methods on instances. Just not vica versa.

Comment: @Balázs to clarify what i meant: you can call static methods inside of an instance method, but you cannot call a static method with a class instance. So in the given code ApplicationUtilities.DisplayApplicationInformation(); would work, but AU.DisplayApplicationInformation(); would not

Comment: I really appreciate you guys' help. One other thing; in the Main class, in my code I have an error as well. I've tried to rewrite it in a few different ways but every way I code it an error. 

        ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Name");--->       name = IU.GetInput("Enter your name");
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);

Comment: Nevermind. Sorry about that. I figured that error out. My program is running pretty good now. Again, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `AU` and `IU` without initializing them. In addition you try to access static methods as non-static methods.

```
//initialize AU and IU
ApplicationUtilities AU = new ApplicationUtilities();
InputUtilities IU = new InputUtilities ();
```

Remove the `static` from all the methods and access them by

```
//call DisplayApplicationInformation()
AU.DisplayApplicationInformation();
```

> Explanation:

`Main()` is `static`, so you have two options to call methods from classes:

- Define the methods in the class as `static`
- Create instance of the class contains the methods.

You did a mix of both, which is bad way.

Comment: I'm not completely understanding. I was told to use 'public static void' but I'm still getting errors. Should I not use AU and IU?

Comment: @mrlljones I added explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are algorithms that belong to the `class` and *not* the `instance`.

With this in mind, this code will fail:

```
ApplicationUtilities AU - new ApplicationUtilities();
AU.DisplayDivider("Name");
```

The reason it fails is because `AU` is an `instance` of the class and not the `class` itself. To have the above code correctly run, call the method through the class itself:

```
ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Name");
```

As pointed out in other answers, you can't call non-static methods from an instance without *instantiating* your object. What you did here:

```
ApplicationUtilities AU;
InputUtilities IU;
```

Is simply *declare* the variable. Let's assume `DisplayDivider()` was a non-static method. The result of:

```
ApplicationUtilities AU;
AU.DisplayDivider("Name");
```

Is a `NullReferenceException` because the default value of an object is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In code that you provided methods `DisplayDivider` and `TerminateApplication` are outside of the `ApplicationUtilities` class.

Also try to add `public` keyword in you `ApplicationUtilities` class definition: `public class ApplicationUtilities`.

By default, in C# classes are **internal** and if your `ApplicationUtilities` class is defined in another project, you won't be able to call his methods.